# How to save KDE Plasma 5 activity configurations?

Tags: linux, kde, kde-plasma-5

I've spent the past two weeks getting warm and fuzzy with KDE Plasma 5 Activities and have *starting an activity pretty much down pat, but *SAVING* the configuration evades me.

(Details on request or when I have time to post them to my URL.)

I've figured out how to set keyboard shortcuts that actually work (D-bus) to switch between activities.

I have written scripts that, starting with an empty session, brings up all the core, common, and activity-specific applications for each activity. So starting and setup are very much under control.

But on reboot, I have to run all those scripts all over again. It would be so cool to be able to specify a set of applications (and their file content, configurations, etc.) and save that, so that on reboot I just open the particular Activity and poof! it's baaack.

Needless to say I have spent hours googling or I wouldn't be here. Thank you in advance.

Best regards, Andy